# Java Selection for calendaring leap year

Tags: java, boolean, selection

How do I get java to apply the selection to leap year? The rule is every 4 years there is a leap year starting from 0. The boolean I made is leapYear = year % 4 == 0 but when I input a leapYear e.g. 4, the if statement (at March) with leapYear outputs blank lines. Here is the code:

```
        public static void main(String[] args) {
// create a scanner
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

//prompt user to enter year and first weekday
System.out.println("Enter a year");
int year = input.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter first weekday of year e.g.: 0 for Sunday");
int weekDay = input.nextInt();
int i;
int jan = 31;
int feb = 28;
int mar = 31;
int apr = 30;
int may = 31;
int jun = 30;
int jul = 31;
int aug = 31;
int sep = 30;
int oct = 31;
int nov = 30;
int dec = 31;
// leap year
boolean leapYear = year % 4 == 0;
if (leapYear) feb += 1;

System.out.println("January " + year);
System.out.println("________________________________");
System.out.println(" Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat");

if (weekDay == 1) System.out.printf("%4s", " ");
if (weekDay == 2) System.out.printf("%8s", " ");
if (weekDay == 3) System.out.printf("%12s", " ");
if (weekDay == 4) System.out.printf("%16s", " ");
if (weekDay == 5) System.out.printf("%20s", " ");
if (weekDay == 6) System.out.printf("%24s", " ");

for (i = 1; i <= jan; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%4d", i);
    if (weekDay == 0 && i % 7 == 0) System.out.println("\n");
    if (weekDay == 1 && (i == 6 || i == 13 || i == 20 || i == 27)) System.out.println("\n");
    if (weekDay == 2 && (i == 5 || i == 12 || i == 19 || i == 26)) System.out.println("\n");
    if (weekDay == 3 && (i == 4 || i == 11 || i == 18 || i == 25)) System.out.println("\n");
    if (weekDay == 4 && (i == 3 || i == 10 || i == 17 || i == 24)) System.out.println("\n");
    if (weekDay == 5 && (i == 2 || i == 9 || i == 16 || i == 23 || i == 30)) System.out.println("\n");
    if (weekDay == 6 && (i == 1 || i == 8 || i == 15 || i == 22 || i == 29)) System.out.println("\n");
    }
System.out.println("\n");
System.out.println("February " + year);
System.out.println("________________________________");
System.out.println(" Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat");
if (weekDay == 0) System.out.printf("%12s", " ");
if (weekDay == 1) System.out.printf("%16s", " ");
if (weekDay == 2) System.out.printf("%20s", " ");
if (weekDay == 3) System.out.printf("%24s", " ");
if (weekDay == 5) System.out.printf("%4s", " ");
if (weekDay == 6) System.out.printf("%8s", " ");
for (i = 1; i <= feb; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%4d", i);
    if (weekDay == 0 && (i == 4 || i == 11 || i == 18 || i == 25)) System.out.println("\n");
    if (weekDay == 1 && (i == 3 || i == 10 || i == 17 || i == 24)) System.out.println("\n");
    if (weekDay == 2 && (i == 2 || i == 9 || i == 16 || i == 23)) System.out.println("\n");
    if (weekDay == 3 && (i == 1 || i == 8 || i == 15 || i == 22)) System.out.println("\n");
    if (weekDay == 4 && i % 7 == 0) System.out.println("\n");
    if (weekDay == 5 && (i == 6 || i == 13 || i == 20 || i == 27)) System.out.println("\n");
    if (weekDay == 6 && (i == 5 || i == 12 || i == 19 || i == 26)) System.out.println("\n");

}

System.out.println("\n");
System.out.println("March " + year);
System.out.println("________________________________");
System.out.println(" Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat");

if (leapYear) {
    if (weekDay == 0) System.out.printf("%4s", " ");
    if (weekDay == 1) System.out.printf("%8s", " ");
    if (weekDay == 2) System.out.printf("%12s", " ");
    if (weekDay == 3) System.out.printf("%16s", " ");
    if (weekDay == 5) System.out.printf("%20s", " ");
    if (weekDay == 6) System.out.printf("%24s", " ");

    for (i = 1; i <= mar; i++) {
        if (weekDay == 6 && (i == 4 || i == 11 || i == 18 || i == 25)) System.out.println("\n");
        if (weekDay == 0 && (i == 3 || i == 10 || i == 17 || i == 24)) System.out.println("\n");
        if (weekDay == 1 &&(i == 2 || i == 9 || i == 16 || i == 23 || i == 30)) System.out.println("\n");
        if (weekDay == 2 &&(i == 1 || i == 8 || i == 15 || i == 22 || i == 29)) System.out.println("\n");
        if (weekDay == 3 && i % 7 == 0) System.out.println("\n");
        if (weekDay == 4 && (i == 6 || i == 13 || i == 20 || i == 27)) System.out.println("\n");
        if (weekDay == 5 && (i == 5 || i == 12 || i == 19 || i == 26)) System.out.println("\n"); 
        }
}
else {
if (weekDay == 0) System.out.printf("%12s", " ");
if (weekDay == 1) System.out.printf("%16s", " ");
if (weekDay == 2) System.out.printf("%20s", " ");
if (weekDay == 3) System.out.printf("%24s", " ");
if (weekDay == 5) System.out.printf("%4s", " ");
if (weekDay == 6) System.out.printf("%8s", " ");

for (i = 1; i <= mar; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%4d", i);
    if (weekDay == 0 && (i == 4 || i == 11 || i == 18 || i == 25)) System.out.println("\n");
    if (weekDay == 1 && (i == 3 || i == 10 || i == 17 || i == 24)) System.out.println("\n");
    if (weekDay == 2 && (i == 2 || i == 9 || i == 16 || i == 23 || i == 30)) System.out.println("\n");
    if (weekDay == 3 && (i == 1 || i == 8 || i == 15 || i == 22 || i == 29)) System.out.println("\n");
    if (weekDay == 4 && i % 7 == 0) System.out.println("\n");
    if (weekDay == 5 && (i == 6 || i == 13 || i == 20 || i == 27)) System.out.println("\n");
    if (weekDay == 6 && (i == 5 || i == 12 || i == 19 || i == 26)) System.out.println("\n");    
}
}
```

Comment: What is the relevance of all this code?

Comment: Write a program that prompts the user to enter the year and
first day of the year and displays the calendar table for the year on the console.

Comment: so this doesn't have to be the "real" dates, if you say 2015 and first day is Sunday then that is okay?

Comment: The weekday must be an int from 0 to 6; 0 is Sunday, 6 is Saturday. The issue is when there is a leapYear I must add a day to February which then shifts all subsequent days by one. I used selection to determine if the computation is for a non-leap year or a leap year. So far my leap year is causing an error in the month of March where the output is 5 blank lines instead of the selection body. I was wondering if someone could see why this is.

Comment: Why don't you try to see why that is, by debugging the code, stepping through it one line at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is difficult to read, but you are missing System.out.printf("%4d", i); in the block under if (leapYear).  However, you are also applying leap year to March...

An alternative approach...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StackOverflow_32900399 {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        try
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a year");
            int year = input.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Enter first weekday of year e.g.: 0 for Sunday");
            int weekDay = input.nextInt();

            for (int month = 1; month <= 12; month++)
            {
                printMonthHeader(month, year);
                weekDay = printDaysOfMonth(month, year, weekDay);
                System.out.println("\n");
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            input.close();
        }
    }

    private static void printMonthHeader(int monthOfYear, int year)
    {       
        String month = "";

        switch (monthOfYear)
        {
            case 1 : month = "January"; break; 
            case 2 : month = "February"; break; 
            case 3 : month = "March"; break; 
            case 4 : month = "April"; break; 
            case 5 : month = "May"; break; 
            case 6 : month = "June"; break; 
            case 7 : month = "July"; break; 
            case 8 : month = "August"; break; 
            case 9 : month = "September"; break; 
            case 10 : month = "October"; break; 
            case 11 : month = "November"; break; 
            case 12 : month = "December"; break; 
        }


        System.out.println(month + " " + year);
        System.out.println("___________________________________");
        System.out.println(" Sun  Mon  Tue  Wed  Thu  Fri  Sat ");
    }

    private static int printDaysOfMonth(int monthOfYear, int year, int startOn)
    {
        int daysInMonth = 0;
        int currentDay = startOn;

        switch(monthOfYear)
        {
            case 4 : 
            case 6 : 
            case 9 : 
            case 11 : 
                daysInMonth = 30;
                break;
            case 2:
                daysInMonth = ((year % 4) == 0 ? 29 : 28);
                break;
            default: 
                daysInMonth = 31;
        }

        StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder();
        if (currentDay != 0)
        {
            buff.append(String.format("%1$"+(5*startOn)+ "s", ""));
        }

        for (int day = 1; day <= daysInMonth; day ++)
        {
            String padding = day > 9 ? "  " : "   ";
            buff.append(padding + day + " ");

            if (currentDay == 6)
            {
                buff.append("\n");
                currentDay = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                currentDay++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(buff.toString());
        System.out.println("___________________________________");
        return currentDay;
    }

}
```

Comment: I came back to update that I also discovered the missing print line in March. Thanks. I will take a lengthy look at the alternative approach; its a little more advanced then what we have covered but I am eager to learn. (Can you tell I am in an intro class?) Thank you Michael.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is that if you are copying and pasting the same code over and over, there is an easier way to do it.  Create methods to perform like operations and better organize your code.  It makes things easier to read and easier to troubleshoot.  If you are using an IDE, learn how to get into debug mode so you can step through line by line and see what is happening as well, comes in REALLY handy.

Comment: Do you have an email address? I really appreciate the information and the sample code.